# When I run Grails console I have the errors

Tags: grails

Errors:

```
| Error 2013-08-08 08:45:14,624 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table student_knowledge_mappings add index FKCA7A648A86D99F36 (updated_by_id), add constraint FKCA7A648A86D99F36 foreign key (updated_by_id) references user (id)
| Error 2013-08-08 08:45:14,626 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SLA`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-1a7c_4'>, CONSTRAINT `FKCA7A648A86D99F36` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
| Error 2013-08-08 08:45:14,671 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table topic_levels_cc add index FKCE4A204F17E447 (topic_id), add constraint FKCE4A204F17E447 foreign key (topic_id) references topic_cc (id)
| Error 2013-08-08 08:45:14,671 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Can't create table 'SLA.#sql-1a7c_4' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: You need to provide more information than just posting your error. Maybe some relevant information from your Datasource.groovy. You database and etc.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs due to inconsistency of mysql engine types set on table structure:

```
driverClassName ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "username"
password = "password"
zeroDateTimeBehavior="convertToNull"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
```

If you are using mysql the first thing to check is to ensure your dialect and ensure you have it set as above..

This now means all your tables should actually be InnoDB..

To do this as a one liner run below changing PASSWORD and DATABASE_NAME to your details:

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME -e  "show table status where Engine='MyISAM';" | awk 'NR>1 {print "ALTER TABLE "$1" ENGINE = InnoDB;"}'  | mysql -u root -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME
```

Alternatively log into mysql and execute this then using output pump it back in to mysql:

```
SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';

SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;') AS sql_statements
FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
WHERE   table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME
AND     `ENGINE` = 'MyISAM'
AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name DESC INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myoutput.sql';

exit;
```

Now from Linux cli:

```
mysql DATABASE_NAME -u root -p < /tmp/myoutput.sql
```

you can also define your default to me InnoDB

```
   mysql> SET SESSION storage_engine = InnoDB;
   mysql> SET GLOBAL storage_engine = InnoDB;
```

But there won't actually be any need since it will be storing everything correctly from there on.

without the dialect defined it will default to the default configuration of mysql which will be MyISAM and you could then reverse all of above to be MyISAM instead of InnoDB

**UPDATED ---- Feb 2015**

Whilst attempting to upgrade I hit this same old issue, this time the solution was slightly different:

```
alter table servers_links add constraint FK_oder1rqc5maeen9dlb9sbpoav foreign key (servers_links_id) references servers (id)
2015-02-09 14:49:12,954 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDB_prod`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-736_d6'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_oder1rqc5maeen9dlb9sbpoav` FOREIGN KEY (`servers_links_id`) REFERENCES `servers` (`id`))
```

so lets track down the entries in  **servers_links**

```
select * from servers_links limit 2;
+------------------+----------+
| servers_links_id | links_id |
+------------------+----------+
|                1 |        3 |



select a.servers_links_id, b.name  FROM  servers_links a LEFT JOIN servers b on a.servers_links_id=b.id where b.name is NULL;
+------------------+------+
| servers_links_id | name |
+------------------+------+
|               89 | NULL |
|               89 | NULL |
|               89 | NULL |
|               91 | NULL |
|               91 | NULL |
|               91 | NULL |
|               93 | NULL |
|               93 | NULL |
|               93 | NULL |
|               95 | NULL |
|               95 | NULL |
|               95 | NULL |
|              111 | NULL |
|              111 | NULL |
|              112 | NULL |
|              112 | NULL |
|              113 | NULL |
|              113 | NULL |
|              114 | NULL |
|              114 | NULL |
+------------------+------+

delete servers_links FROM servers_links LEFT JOIN servers ON servers_links.servers_links_id=servers.id where servers.name IS NULL;
Query OK, 20 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

What we had above is 20 records on the table that was mapped to non existant entries within servers table.

Using the above delete command it has now removed those bad entries.

I have used the above formulae on multiple db relations and it works the same, just replace the fields with the fields that match your table with conflict